# Checking if user input is a string

Tags: c#

```
public int GetFuelToBurn(MarsLander ml)
        {
            int nFuel = 0;
            int fuelPoints = ml.GetFuelPoints();
            bool checker = false;
            
            while(checker == false)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("How many points of fuel would you like to burn?");
                Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out nFuel);

                int currentFuel = fuelPoints;

                if (nFuel < 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You can't burn less than 0 points of fuel!");                  
                }
                if (nFuel % 1 != 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You need to type a whole number of fuel points to burn!");                    
                }
                if (currentFuel < nFuel)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You don't have {0} points of fuel!", nFuel);                    
                }
                else
                {
                    checker = true;
                    currentFuel = fuelPoints - nFuel;
                    ml.SetFuel(currentFuel);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Just as a reminder, here's where the lander is: ");
                PrintLanderInfo(ml);
            }

            return nFuel;
          
        }
```

This is the current code that I have and the user will input a value and store it into nFuel, but after whenever I type a word like hello is just continues. What I need is something to check if nFuel is a number but I cant think of any methods that do this, thanks for the help!

Comment: `Checking if user input is a string` Well, it is definitely a string.

Comment: An `int` will always be a whole number so there's no point in the `nFuel % 1 != 0` check.  But really you should check the result of `int.TryParse` to find out if they entered something that's not an `int` value, like "five" or even "2.5".

Answer (score 0):

> What I need is something to check if nFuel is a number but I cant think of any methods that do this

You already have it in your code:

`Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out nFuel);`

TryParse returns a boolean. Please read more from here on how to use it and modify *your* code accordingly: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=net-5.0